# php parse XPath in string variable of html content

Tags: php, xpath

I have a string variable of contents such as:

```
$str = '<img src="ptah/to/image.ext"><br>some text <b>text agian</b> etc';
```

I need to use Xpath to evaluate the image src attribute in that string `//img/@src`. However, from the [domXPath documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) we have to load document from a file:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->Load('book.xml');
```

My question is: Is there any other method than Load or any workaround to load the dom from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$doc->loadXML('<img src="path/to/image.ext><br>some text <b>text agian</b> etc');
```

If it is not standard XML input, you have to use `loadHTML()`

Comment: I tried `loadXML` but it generated error because the string supplied is not standard XML. I bit and tried `loadHTML` it worked fine. Now, I'd like to know where could I find documentation for DOMDocument object's methods? Thank you.